# Ubuntu 22 package management broken

Tags: apt, package-management, python

Package management seems to have gotten into a mess. apt upgrade gives me:

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libpython3-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (>= 3.10.6-1~) but it is not installed
 python3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.11-1+focal1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

But then if I run apt --fix-broken install:

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libpython3-stdlib python3 python3-apt python3-pkg-resources python3-yaml python3.10 ubuntu-advantage-tools
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 7 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 3,546 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 271677 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.14.4~22.04) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/apt.py", line 14, in <module>
    import apt  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from apt.package import Package as Package, Version as Version
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 32, in <module>
    from http.client import BadStatusLine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http'
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--remove):
 installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm guessing python is completely borked, but I don't know how to begin fixing it when apt is also borked. sudo apt clean hasn't helped, but I'm way beyond that...

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: This like a classic self-inflicted version conflict. It would help a lot to know the last package actions that worked, as that's what likely caused the problem. See /var/log/apt to refresh your memory, if needed. `apt clean` may have been unwise; it deleted the older packages that you may need to reinstall.

Comment: I think I've solved it by manually downloading the debs for python 3.10 (and the dependencies) and installing them. Python then works. I then deleted all python packages (not needed, as apps are all in venvs) and touch wood things are now working.

Comment: That looks like a 22.04 or 22.10 system, and not 22 (*Ubuntu uses the year format for snap only products, like Ubuntu Core 22 - these don't use* `apt`).  Your packages don't look correct for either 22.04 or 22.10 though !  being `libpython3.10-stdlib | 3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1 | jammy-updates    | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` or `libpython3.10-stdlib | 3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3       | kinetic-updates  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`

Comment: You're right - it was 22.04. The problem turned out to be a python repo from "deadsnakes" that I'd added, and had resulted in some python packages being updated but others not. I don't know why. Replaced everything with the standard 22.04 packages and seems fine now.